# Wrong value while converting UTC date to a given timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert a UTC date String of the format `2020-06-09T06:30:00Z` to a Timezone like `Asia/Calcutta`.

The time offset between `UTC` and `Asia/Calcutta` is `+5:30`, so the expected result on converting `2020-06-09T06:30:00Z` to `Asia/Calcutta` is `2020-06-09T12:00:00Z` but I am getting `2020-06-09T01:00:00Z`

```
    String utcDate = "2020-06-09T06:30:00Z";
    String timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(utcDate, formatter);          //2020-06-09T06:30
    ZonedDateTime zonedDate = ZonedDateTime.of(date, ZoneId.of(timezone)); //2020-06-09T06:30+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
    Date dateConverted = Date.from( zonedDate.toInstant());                //Tue Jun 09 01:00:00 UTC 2020
```

I think `zonedDate.toInstant()` is converting subtracting `5:30` instead of adding `5:30` to `2020-06-09T06:30`. My machine is in UTC timezone. may be its converting to local time don't know what is the issue. Also tried below method, still same issue.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));
sdf.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: I think you are doing it wrongly. When you parse your date and set timezone. It will understand that 06:30 is in GMT+5:30 time zone. Then later when you print it out. It will print GMT+0 value. To convert it as you want. Parse it first by zonedDateTime

Comment: @user3562932 Yes. Got it to work using SimpleDateFormat just now. If you can post the correction using ZonedDateTime that would be helpful also

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer. It will help other readers that the question is clearly marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

I agree with you, you should strongly prefer to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It’s not complicated when you know how.

```
    String utcDate = "2020-06-09T06:30:00Z";
    String timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";

    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(timezone);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.parse(utcDate).atZone(zone);

    System.out.println("zdt: " + zdt);
```

Output is:

> zdt: 2020-06-09T12:00+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]

You notice that the time of day in the `ZonedDateTime` is 12:00 as you had expected. The trailing `Z` that you also said you expected is wrong, though. `Z` means an offset of 0 from UTC, so since the offset is +05:30, we are very happy *not* to have the `Z` there.

If what you needed was an old-fashioned `Date` object, presumably for a legacy API that you don’t want to upgrade just now, there’s no reason to convert to your time zone first. This works:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(Instant.parse(utcDate));
    System.out.println("oldfashionedDate: " + oldfashionedDate);
```

Output in my time zone is:

> oldfashionedDate: Tue Jun 09 08:30:00 CEST 2020

You may be in doubt whether the `Date` is right. It is. Since I am in Europe/Copenhagen time zone, currently at offset +02:00, the `Date` prints in this time zone, so the time of day is 8:30 (the `Date` doesn’t hold a time zone or offset). If instead I run in Asia/Calcutta time zone:

> oldfashionedDate: Tue Jun 09 12:00:00 IST 2020

You notice `IST` for India Standard Time instead of `CEST` for Central European Summer Time. And the time is 12:00 as expected.

### Points for you to take with you

- Never hardcode `Z` as a literal in a format pattern string. As I said, it’s an offset, so it needs to be parsed as an offset.
- For the same reason don’t parse into a `LocalDateTime`. A `LocalDateTime`. hasn’t got any offset, so you are losing information.
- In this case use no formatter at all. Your format is ISO 8601, and `Instant` parses it as its default, that is, without any explicit formatter (`OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` do too).
- Make the conversion *from* UTC *to* Asia/Calcutta. It seems to me that you were doing the opposite conversion.

### Link

[Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: utcDate is a String received from a 3rd party API, the 'Z' is not added by me and timezone can be any timezone which is also from the API not my system timezone. I just posted that for example

Comment: Alright, @Thanthu, does any of that pose any problem? Does the UTC date-time always come with a trailing `Z`? If not, what else could it look like? My answer and code will work with any ISO 8601 date-time string ending in `Z` and with any [IANA time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: Yes, It always comes with a trailing `Z`. Your answer is well explained. I'll up vote. Will accept answer once I try it out. However the issue was solved before, as you've have mentioned the opposite was happening in my case

Answer (score 0):

Got it work using `SimpleDateFormat` as shown below. But anyone coming across this issue should probably use `ZonedDateTime`.

```
String utcDate = "2020-06-09T06:30:00Z";
String timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = sdf1.parse(utcDate);       // Tue Jun 09 06:30:00 UTC 2020

SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));

String sDateInZone = sdf2.format(date);      // 09-6-2020 12:00:00 PM
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date dateInZone = formatter.parse(sDateInZone);    // Tue Jun 09 12:00:00 UTC 2020
```

**EDIT:** Got it to work using `ZonedDateTime` also as shown below:

```
String utcDate = "2020-06-09T06:30:00Z";
String timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
LocalDateTime dateUtc = LocalDateTime.parse(utcDate, formatter);
ZonedDateTime utcZonedDateTime = dateUtc.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(timezone);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = utcZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(zoneId);
String zoneDateString = formatter.format(zonedDateTime);

Date date = Date.from(LocalDateTime.parse(zoneDateString, formatter).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Comment: From your `ZonedDateTime` code I get `Tue Jun 09 06:30:00 IST 2020`, which is incorrect. I repeat, don’t hardcode `Z` as a literal in the format pattern strings, this is what is giving you the incorrect result.